# Why is my C Code miscalculating

Tags: c, scanf, integer-division

I'm trying to write a formula to calculate the volume of a sphere with user inputting the radius. The formula is `V = (4/3)PI r*r*r`. I can't figure out why my code is just saying the volume is 1 no matter what the input is. Here is what I'm using:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    float pi, r, v;

    pi = 3.1416;

    printf("What is the radius?\n");
    scanf("%d", &r);

    v = ((4/3) * pi) * r * r * r;

    printf("Volume of the sphere is: %d\n", v);

    if (v>10)
        printf("Volume is greater than 10");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", &r);` is wrong. Consult the documentation.

Comment: `4/3` evaluates to 1.

Comment: `(4/3)` -> `(4.0/3.0)`.

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Going to SO is not a recommended debugging technique. You'd be better served if you learn to help yourself.

Comment: %d in printf expects an integer argument, but you're passing float, which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: First problem: Enable all compiler warnings. A good compiler will warn about `float r; ... scanf("%d", &r);`,  This saves you time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems as I see it.

First of all,

```
  scanf("%d", &r);
```

should be

```
 scanf("%f", &r);
```

as `r` is a `float`. Passing an incompatible type as argument causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Please double-check the format specifier and the supplied argument type.

The same is applicable for

```
     printf("Volume of the sphere is: %d\n", v);
```

also, as `%f`  expects a `float` (or `double`, to be exact, a `float`, after default argument promotion gets promoted to a `double`, anyway), **not** `%d`.

With additional options enabled compiler are likely to warn you about the mismatch (at least, `gcc` can do that). Enable all warnings and it should point out the issue for you.

Then, later

```
   v = ((4/3) * pi) * r * r * r;
```

the `4/3` yields an integer division (giving `1`) so it will not do what you think it does. You need to enforce floating point division, if you want it, with something like:

```
v = (pi * 4 / 3) * r * r * r;
```

(where the `float pi` multiplied by `4` gives a float, that *stays* a `float` when dividing by `3`).

Comment: @StoryTeller Sure, sure, I was not contradicting you, just amended my answer, it's a nice addition.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it perfectly!

Comment: @SouravGhosh: you might also add that the value of `pi` is not as precise as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Modified code for calculating volume of a sphere.

```
int main(void) {

    float pi, r, v;

    pi = 3.1416;

    printf("What is the radius?\n");
    scanf("%f", &r); //%d is for integers and %f is for float

    v = ((4.0/3.0) * pi) * r * r * r; // (4/3) typecasts to an integer and results to 1

    printf("Volume of the sphere is: %f\n", v); //%d is for integers and %f is for float

    if (v>10)
        printf("Volume is greater than 10\n");

    return 0;
}
```